# Django form password TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget'

Tags: python, django

I have this code in my models.py:

```
from django import forms

class user_Account(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
        verbose_name="Password",
        max_length=500,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

This is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from Account.models import user_Account

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = user_Account
```

Why am I getting this error?

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget'
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the widget in the column of Model. Because widget is the keyword argument of the form's field.

```
class user_Account(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(verbose_name="Password", max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
```

form.py

```
from django import forms
from Account.models import user_Account
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = user_Account
```

Comment: what should i do? ahmm can you post your answer?

Comment: Sure Give me a second

Comment: Can you check my new post. I just remove the widget argument in models.py